# How to verify my smartcontract/program as creator on metaplex minted NFT using rust?

Tags: metaplex, rust, nft, nfts, anchor-spl

I want to add my program/smart-contract as creator and verify that. I am using anchor and mpl library on rust.

```
pub fn mint_nft(
        ctx: Context<MintNFT>,
        creator_key: Pubkey,
        uri: String,
        title: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Initializing Mint Ticket");
        let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        };
        msg!("CPI Accounts Assigned");
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        msg!("CPI Program Assigned");
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
        msg!("CPI Context Assigned");
        token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
        msg!("Token Minted !!!");
        let account_info = vec![
            ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        ];
        msg!("Account Info Assigned");
        let creator = vec![
            mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
                address: creator_key,
                verified: false,
                share: 100,
            },
            mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
                address: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                verified: false,
                share: 0,
            },
            mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
                address: *ctx.program_id,
                verified: true,
                share: 0,
            },
        ];
        msg!("Creator Assigned");
        let symbol = std::string::ToString::to_string("symb");
        invoke(
            &create_metadata_accounts_v2(
                ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
                ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                title,
                symbol,
                uri,
                Some(creator),
                1,
                true,
                false,
                None,
                None,
            ),
            account_info.as_slice(),
        )?;
        msg!("Metadata Account Created !!!");
        let master_edition_infos = vec![
            ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        ];
        msg!("Master Edition Account Infos Assigned");
        invoke(
            &create_master_edition_v3(
                ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
                ctx.accounts.master_edition.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                Some(0),
            ),
            master_edition_infos.as_slice(),
        )?;
        msg!("Master Edition Nft Minted !!!");

        Ok(())
    }
```

However, I am getting error on making verified: true for my program-id. I tried calling invoke_signed as well, but didn't work. Any suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Posting the full text/stacktrace of the error will be helpful to identify where and why things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only sign with a [**PDA**](https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/pdas.html#facts) derived from the program, not with the program by itself.

[image]